# Interface for viewing demographic information in maps

Tags: user-interface, geospatial, data-visualization, openstreetmap, user-experience

I am involved in a research project where we try to find correlation between demographics and restaurant types.  We want to have an interface where we can apply the demographic information over a map of the city as filters and check how the restaurant types and information changes.

I am lost on what sort of tools to use for this purpose.

Note: I am not sure whether this is the right place to post this question.  If there is a specific SO site for this, I will move it there.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a specific SO site for openstreetmap, but even better there is a https://help.openstreetmap.org/ site which would be an even better place to ask.